# How to restore the original color of a button and not JButton from a CSS Styles Sheet after fade transition?

Tags: java, css

When the fade animation finish the color of the buttons keep the same fade value and not restore the original one. The animations are being played multiple times and I want to restore the color as it was at the beginning.

```
public class launcher extends Application implements EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>{

        ParallelTransition pr4 = new ParallelTransition(btn3,cran,fd);
        pr4.play();

    }
}
```

when the fade transition ends it the color is still fade out and not the original bright color.

Comment: 1) *"of a button and not JButton"* .. What? If it's not a `JButton`, then which GUI toolkit is being referenced here? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: but it didn't want to add the JButton from getchildrean, till i changed it to Button

Comment: Is it using Java-FX? Note that if there was now an MCVE  / SSCCE that included the import statements and a `main(String[])` method, I'd already know, and be able to add the tags that will get the attention of the people best able to help.